# App keeps crashing at start up after I used AdMob

Tags: android, admob

My app just keeps crashing after I tryed to use *banner ads with AdMob* (without it everything works just fine). The *SplashScreen* loads but the app crashes when the game should start. Here are the steps that I followed to implemet this:

1) I made sure that I have installed *Google Play Services* and *Google Repository*

2) Then I connected my app to *Firebase* using *Firebase Tool Assistant* ( it just added *google services.json* under the *app folder* in my project )

3)Then I added the *AdMob* to my app, as shown here:[image]

4)I added this codes in my layout:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

5)In my *Main Activity* class called "Game" I added this code to *onCreate()* method as you can see here:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

//ADMOB
private AdView mAdView;

MediaPlayer sound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //turn title off
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //set to full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

    //ADMOB

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    int[] sounds={R.raw.chiptune, R.raw.chiptune1, R.raw.chiptune2, R.raw.chiptune3};
    Random r = new Random();
    int Low = 0;
    int High = 4;
    int rand = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    sound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rand]);
    sound.start();
    sound.setLooping(true);
}
```

6) Add this to my strings: `<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>`

7) In my AndroidManifest.xml I added this pieces of codes:

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

I wounder what's wrong, if anybody can help!

**Here is the *Crash Log*:**
[image]

Comment: please crash log ?

Comment: Hi! I added the crash log. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById(R.id.adView);` returns a View if it exists in the layout you provided in setContentView(), otherwise it returns null and that's what happening to you.

mAdView is null so you're getting null pointer exception.

So create a layout.xml, embed GamePanel view and AdView both then pass that layout to setContentView(); method.

Comment: @MoisoniIonut show my code on GamePanel, what is it ?